# "What's her" vs. "What's hers"

Tags: possessives

Can you tell and explain, which one is grammatically correct?

> My excuse is that I am a kid, what's **her**?

or

> My excuse is that I am a kid, what's **hers**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second is correct, ending in "what is **hers**?".

I can see why this would be confusing.  If the word "excuse" were repeated in the second clause, it would be "what is her excuse?". Perfectly grammatical. But the reality is that "excuse" is not repeated. So *her* stands on its own, and it must become possessive to represent the missing word "excuse". That is why the example must be worded:

> My excuse is that I am a kid, what's hers?

Comment: How does that work with names? "My excuse is that I am a kid, what's Mary's (excuse)?" Is the repetition of excuse necessary or not?

Comment: @Jakub No, repeating the word "excuse" is not necessary, but it would be fine to do so. The only difference is that the proper noun **Mary** has to be specifically possessive whether or not **excuse** is there.  The pronoun **her** only takes its possessive form when **excuse** is absent. See Laurel's answer.

Comment: nope, I'm here RichF and thanks for your answer, greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Che... glad to hear it!  Earlier it was not possible to click into your profile from the icon below your question.  Maybe the system was just slow to link in that info.

Comment: @RichF Until the user manually creates an account on the site the question was migrated to, you can't click on the profile link because it does not exist.  All it means is that the user doesn't have a profile here.

Comment: @Catija Thank you; I should have realized that. An account at english.stackexchange.com is not an account at ell.stackexchange.com, nor automatically created if there was a migrated question or answer.Got it!

Comment: There seems to be a fairly widely-held notion that _her_ in "her excuse" is already possessive (http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/261843/her-a-determiner-or-a-pronoun) and does not "become" possessive when you change it to _hers._ Even Laurel's answer, which you refer to, says _her_ is possessive.

Answer (score 4):

The second one is correct:

> My excuse is that I am a kid, what's hers?

Wikipedia, on its [page here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)#Nominal_ellipsis) points out this is a "nominal ellipsis with [a] possessive determiner". In other words, it's an ellipsis.

The full sentence would be:

> My excuse is that I am a kid, what's her excuse?

However, when the word *excuse* is elided, the possessive determiner *her* becomes the possessive pronoun *hers*.

Answer (score 4):

As others have explained,

> My excuse is that I am a kid, what's hers?

is correct and

> My excuse is that I am a kid, what's her?

is incorrect.

### Some "determiner" words in English cannot end a phrase

"Her" is used correctly in the following sentence:

> My excuse is that I am a kid, what's her excuse?

The possesive word "her" is used as a "determiner" in English. Other examples of determiners are the definite article "the" and the indefinite article "a/an".

Some common English determiners, including **"her", "the" and "a/an", cannot be the last word in a phrase**; they need to be followed by a noun phrase.

When you don't have a particular noun phrase in mind, you have to use a generic noun phrase or a pronoun:

- "What's **her** excuse?" > "What's **hers**?" (*her* > *hers*)
- "Give me **a** french fry." > "Give me **one**." (*a* > an indefinite pronoun like *one*)
- "I want to read **the** book." > "I want to read **it**." (*the* > a personal pronoun like *it*)

Other possessive words like "her":

- *my* _ (replace with "mine" when it is the last word in a phrase)
- *your* _ (replace with "yours")
- *our* _ ("ours")
- *their* _ ("theirs")

These determiners are not only used directly before noun phrases, but also before coordinating conjunctions such as "and" or "or" in constructions with ellipsis where there is a noun phrase further on in the sentence:

> "your and my ideas" = "your ideas and my ideas"

"Your ideas and mine" would also be correct, but *"your ideas and my" is incorrect.

### But other determiner words *can* be used as complete noun phrases

But other words can function either as determiners or as complete noun phrases. For example, the demonstratives *this, that, these, those* are all fine either with a following noun phrase ("Who's that singer?") or no following noun phrase ("Who's that?").

The possessive word "his" can be used both ways.

> My excuse is that I am a kid, what's his excuse?
>
> My excuse is that I am a kid, what's his?

(both correct)

So can the possessive of any ordinary noun, like "Mary's".

> My excuse is that I am a kid, what's Mary's excuse?
>
> My excuse is that I am a kid, what's Mary's?

(both correct)

Comment: Nice detailed answer, +1. Let me add that the pronouns "his" and "its" are special.  Unlike "her"::"hers", they have no alternative forms for possession.  I assume this is because it would be too hard to say "hisz".

Comment: @RichF: I left out "its" because it seems so odd usually to say something like "That's its!" (compared to "That's his" or "That's hers"). You're right that it's possible, as explained by the answers to this ELU question: [“Its” as a Possessive Pronoun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76337)

Comment: sumelic, thanks for the link.  Interesting.  I'm not sure it was necessary to find examples from classic works, though. Someone well might say today, "I drank my water, the fish drank its." I think the only thing that makes it relatively rare is that we seldom think of objects or animals having possessions. Plus we usually refer to mammals by sex. (I couldn't tell you about a goldfish.)

Answer (score 0):

**BASIC GRAMMAR**: Reminder

**Nouns**=mine, yours, his, her**s**, ours, yours, theirs.

These nouns work like any other nouns.

- "This is my excuse. What's **theirs**?"
- "Here are my shoes. Where're yours? Or his?"

**Possessive Adjectives**: my book, your book, his book, her book, our book, your book, their book.

Please note: his is the same whether it's a noun or possessive adjective.